# Can I create a static library in C++11 and call it from C++03?

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking

If I create a C++03-compatible header, and use the same compiler (g++), will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes. Once a module is compiled, the interface tends to be the most important part.

There may be ABI issues, though, depending on whether name mangling or anything like that changed. If you can use it as a shared library, there's a decent chance you can use it statically as well.

More important, however, is standard library versions. Those very likely changed, so passing std objects between the two should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Is there any other way to interoperate between C++11 and C++03?

Comment: Any method that hides the code and provides a compatible header *should* work. The main issue is getting `std` stuff out of the headers, which can be a pain. I prefer using shared objects of some sort, which typically sidesteps most issues, and haven't really explored others so well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably do it this way.

Comment: Inline functions and templates could be somewhat tricky, as they'll be compiled by the C++03 compiler, not the C++11 one.

Comment: We'll see, I will try to not use too much template magic. Also, for anyone coming here from google: a useful pattern in this scenario is the pimpl/d-pointer pattern (not for the template problem, but binary compatibility in general).